# Sencha Touch Production Build not working

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Im new to Sencha touch. I copied the demo of blog example shown in documentation video

**Environment**
Sencha 2.2.0 Aplha
Sencha Cmd 3.0.2.288
Google Chrome

When i try to build testing, nothing worked, i followed the link (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?253688) then testing working..

When i build the production, build successful, and nothing loading just loading indicators flashing
i see the following in chrome log

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest 
http:/mydomain:88/apm/build/apm/production/cache.appcache
Application Cache Checking event
XHR finished loading: "http://mydomain:88/apm/build/apm/production/app.json?
1360863591949".
Application Cache NoUpdate event
```

Please let me know, if i miss anything?

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: Do you have any errors in your debugging console? If the app fails to get past the loading indicators, you might normally see a JS error of some kind or a message stating some required class can't be found.

Comment: I dont see any errors in console.. that's the problem

Comment: Just for testing purpose, I've created a new blank app with sencha defualt one, and build as testing and production versions. I encountered 2 issues 1. "Shell script returned 1" and  2. "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'filterPlatform'" .. i fix these problems and build production, and that one also not working..

Comment: what if you dont use cache manifest at all ? does it work that way ?

Comment: Hello all.. Still i've issues.. any help please.

Comment: @Pavan can you give me solution for #<Object> has no method 'filterPlatform'" problem ?. I have same issue.